# Is it unprofessional to ask to use a vacation day for the final day of my notice period?

Tags: professionalism, quitting, notice-period, vacation

My current job is ending soon on a Monday and very soon I am also joining a different position at another company. Problem is I want to make some travel plans on weekend (being a weekend is crucial for me). I also get two paid vacation every month (I still have one left for this month).

I was wondering if I can quit job and say Good Bye to everyone on Friday and take a paid vacation on Monday. **Will asking this look unprofessional? How can I approach my boss with this request?**

Comment: Your job is ending on Monday. Is this the end of a contract that your boss is aware of? Or are you planning to quit but haven't given notice yet?

Comment: Check your employee handbook. Some companies don't allow vacation time to be used during the notice period.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it unprofessional to ask for vacation in your notice period?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76466/is-it-unprofessional-to-ask-for-vacation-in-your-notice-period)

Comment: @DavidK Bah, I went looking for a dupe but didn't find anything. I suppose the fact that it's a single final day and a Monday and that OP is asking for advice on how to make the request might distinguish this question sufficiently. But if it's closed I'll probably move my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're asking something truly outrageous, it's almost always fine to ask for something, provided that you do so respectfully and that you're prepared to take no for an answer.

The fact that it's a single Monday works in your favour. The fact that you didn't ask about this when you handed in your notice works against you, as does asking about this so late into your notice period as I'm assuming you've already started it. But it's perfectly possible for your manager to decline your request and you need to be prepared to accept that. You can phrase it like this:

> Since I have a vacation day left and my final day would fall on a Monday I was wondering if it would be possible to use that vacation day then, so my last day in the office would be the Xth while the Yth would be a paid vacation day.

Whether they allow it or not is a different matter and down to company policy, your workload and the relationship with your management. It's very common for US companies to not respect accrued PTO when someone resigns, though some states have laws requiring them to pay those out. Notice periods are much longer in Europe (months, not weeks) and it's very common to use remaining vacation days for the final X days of your notice period. So you run the risk of them actually putting your final day on that Friday and not paying out your vacation day.

Answer (score 2):

In most locales, you are entitled to be paid for all accrued vacation time.

If your last day in work is a Friday, and you have one accrued vacation day, then you will get paid for that day. It doesn't matter if you travel on Monday or twiddle your thumbs, you'll still be paid for one day.

And no company I know of would keep you on the books for the following Monday. As of the end of the day Friday, you'll no longer be an employee.

Use your 1-day of accrued vacation pay on Monday, or any other day that suits your needs. Or just put it in the bank.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is all based on the policies of the company or your contract if you are a contractor versus employee.

I can tell you in the US, most companies will not allow you to use vacation time as part of your notice period.  As long as you work your notice and turn in all company property, you typically get paid either all or a portion of your accrued paid time off. Attempting to use vacation time as part of your notice is considered unprofessional.

What you could do is give yourself a break between the end of your current job and the beginning of your new one.  This would be unpaid of course, unless as I mentioned above your current employer pays out un-used paid time off.

Comment: This is an example of a cultural difference. I assume your assertion that it "is considered unprofessional" should be considered qualified by your earlier "in the US" statement.  

 In the UK, it would be a little unusual for someone who has accrued paid vacation time NOT to use it in the way the OP describes.  In the UK as well it is the law that the employer has no choice but to pay for unused vacation time.

Answer (score -3):

Depends on if you have some crucial work to finish, or scheduled things to do. If neither, I think it will be ok to ask for the day off.