# Holidays and Notice period

Tags: united-kingdom, notice-period, holidays

I've recently been accepted for a job I applied for and will be partaking in my 4 week notice period, but, prior to the job offer I booked 8 working days off (3/4 weeks ago) for August in my current job.

Would that notice period still be four weeks or would I need to add 8 working days on as-well to account for the holiday?

Comment: You should ask your HR representative.

Comment: The 4 weeks notice can consist of holiday days. This is normal and pretty much expected. You should clear up with your manager in case you're needed at all.

Comment: @MisterPositive We don't have a HR department, we can only ask the CEO and I want to be delicate about the process before I hand in my notice.

Comment: Ah, then I would ask whoever approved your initial time off request.

Comment: @MisterPositive I'll just find out when I hand my notice in then, thanks.

Comment: Does the 8 days you're taking off fall within your notice period?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Is it unprofessional to ask for vacation in your notice period?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76466/is-it-unprofessional-to-ask-for-vacation-in-your-notice-period)

Comment: @thebluefox it does yes, but I booked it off over a month go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still have sufficient holiday days remaining in your *adjusted* yearly entitlement, then you are entitled to take the time off as originally planned and it would not count against your notice period.  Four weeks notice would still be 4 weeks notice, your leaving date would not change.

However - because you're leaving the company mid-way through the year, any holiday entitlement you may get, will be adjusted down on a pro-rata basis. The amount depends on your total entitlement for the year (not including public holidays), so if you get 25 days for the year (as an example), you would accrue approx 2.1 holiday days per month from the start of the holiday year in your organisation.  *Note: this isn't always January to December, but will be defined within your organisation somewhere, possibly within your employee handbook, if you have one.*

So if your holiday year runs from Jan to December, you would accrue 2.1 x 8 (months - Jan-August) = around 17 days holiday.  If you've enough days "in the pot", then you can take the 8 working days.  If not... you probably won't be able to take all the time off you wanted.

In addition, your employer may ask you to consider not using the holiday  if there is a handover period.  There is no reason for you to do this, this would be your decision and would generally only be used to smooth any handover process.

This [UK Govt guidance](https://www.gov.uk/holiday-entitlement-rights/taking-holiday-before-leaving-a-job) may clear up any questions.

Comment: It is from Jan to Dec and I haven't nearly taken 17 days, thanks for the information

Comment: Excellent answer - summed up what I was going to write perfectly.